# WordPress doesn't let me use my print button

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, elementor

I'm having a problem with my Wordpress...

I want to add a print button on my page that prints an image on my page. But every tutorial I find just doesn't work on Wordpress, although working on Codepen, Stackoverflow replies, or on local html files on my laptop...

For exemple, [this code](https://codepen.io/JefMari/pen/jqPJdV) works perfectly, but not on my page. I tried putting the HTML code in a HTML section and the JS in the page settings of Elementor. I've also tried putting everything in the HTML.

I can't seem to find a solution. Maybe Wordpress blocks my Javascript ?

If someone could help me, you'd be my lifesaver! Thank you

Code pen code (that i have adapted for my image):

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" id="printTable">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>      
        <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>      
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>        
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>        
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>        
        <td>67</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
<br />
<br />
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" id="notPrintTable">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>      
        <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>       
        <td>000</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
<br />
<br />

<button>Print me</button>
```

```
function printData()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}

$('button').on('click',function(){
printData();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add jquery 3 cdn and check if works

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work. Besides, I see that it's already added in the source code

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a basic mistake here. In WordPress, `$` will give you undefined. you'll have to use `jQuery` to access the jquery object in WordPress.

So whenever you work with WordPress jquery either wrap your Js code withing `document.ready`

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
// Your code goes here.
} );
```

or you can wrap it within a function like this:

```
( function( $ ) {
// Your code goes here.
}( jQuery ) );
```

Then you can use `$` since we have passed in function as jQuery reference(I don't know what should I call it reference or something else, Correct me in the comments please)

So your code should be like this:

```
( function( $ ) {
    function printData() {
        const divToPrint = document.getElementById( 'printTable' );
        const newWin = window.open( '' );
        newWin.document.write( divToPrint.outerHTML );
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
    }

    $( 'button' ).on( 'click', function() {
        printData();
    } );
}( jQuery ) );
```